# How to use the allow method in RSpec to mock a function inside a controller that is inside a module (Module > Controller > Function)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write the `allow` method in RSpec. My rails controller is

```
module Users
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

    # Update user profile
    def update

      payload = { name: params[:user][:name],email: params[:user][:email]}
      response = send_request_to_update_in_company(payload)
      if response['code'] == 200
        if  User.first.update(user_params) 
          render json: { message: "User successfully updated"}, status: :ok
        else
          head :unprocessable_entity
        end
      else
       render json: { error: 'Error updating user in Company' },status: :unprocessable_entity
     end

   end

   private

   def send_request_to_update_in_comapny(payload)
    response = Api::V1::CompanyRequestService.new(
      payload: payload.merge(company_api_access_details),
      url: 'customers/update_name_email',
      request_method: Net::HTTP::Post
      ).call
    JSON.parse(response.body)
   end
  end
end
```

When I write the bellow code in my test file

```
allow(Users::ProfilesController).to receive(:send_request_to_update_in_company).and_return({ 'code' => 500 })
```

I am getting the following error in terminal

```
Users::ProfilesController does not implement: send_request_to_update_in_comapny
enter code here
```

With allow_any_instance_of I am able to get the code working. But how can I implement it using allow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `allow_any_instance_of` works because, as the name suggests, it allows any **instance** of `Users::ProfilesController` to respond to the **instance method** `send_request_to_update_in_company` with your mock return value.

However, your line

```
allow(Users::ProfilesController).to receive(:send_request_to_update_in_company)
```

is telling RSpec to mock a **class method** called `send_request_to_update_in_company`, which doesn't exist. And so, you're seeing the error message saying so.

You don't say where your test is situated, but generally wherever it is, it's not a good idea to either test or stub out a private method.

I'd be inclined to instead create a mock `Api::V1::CompanyRequestService` object to return a fake response, which your controller code can then parse as expected and produce the expected JSON. For example

```
mock_request = instance_double(Api::V1::CompanyRequestService)
allow(mock_request).to receive(:call).and_return('{"code": 500}')
allow(Api::V1::CompanyRequestService).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_request)
```

Another approach might be to leave your service alone, and instead use tools like `VCR` or `WebMock` to provide mocked JSON values at the network layer - your code can think it's calling out to the internet, but really it gets back responses that you define in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way:

spec/requests/users/profiles_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Users::ProfilesControllers", type: :request do
  describe "Test call to special function: " do
    let(:controller) { Users::ProfilesController.new }
    it "Should response to code 500" do
      response = controller.send_request_to_update_in_company("test")
      expect(response).to eq({"code"=>"500", "test1"=>"abc", "test2"=>"def"})
    end
    it "Should return to true" do
      response = controller.true_flag?
      expect(response).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users/profiles_controller.rb

```
module Users
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    # Update user profile
    def update
      payload = { name: params[:user][:name],email: params[:user][:email]}
      response = send_request_to_update_in_company(payload)
      Rails.logger.debug "Ok71 = response['code'] = #{response['code']}"
      # if response['code'] == 200
      #   if  User.first.update(user_params) 
      #     render json: { message: "User successfully updated"}, status: :ok
      #   else
      #     head :unprocessable_entity
      #   end
      # else
      #  render json: { error: 'Error updating user in Company' },status: :unprocessable_entity
      # end
    end

    # Not private, and not mistake to 'send_request_to_update_in_comapny'
    def send_request_to_update_in_company(payload)
      response = Api::V1::CompanyRequestService.new(
        payload: "for_simple_payload_merge_values",
        url: 'for_simple_customers/update_name_email',
        request_method: "for_simple_request_method"
        ).call
      Rails.logger.debug "Ok66 = Start to log response"
      Rails.logger.debug response
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    # Simple function to test
    def true_flag?
      true
    end

  end
end
```

app/services/api/v1/company_request_service.rb

```
class Api::V1::CompanyRequestService < ActionController::API
  def initialize(payload="test1", url="test2", request_method="test3")
    @payload = payload
    @url = url
    @request_method = request_method
  end
  def call
    @object = Example.new
    @object.body = {code: "500", test1: "abc", test2: "def"}.to_json
    return @object
  end
end

class Example
  attr_accessor :body
  def initialize(body={code: "000", test1: "init_value_abc", test2: "init_value_def"}.to_json)
    @body = body
  end
end
```

I use simple code to simulate your project. Modify it to suitable your working! Tell me about your its thinking. Thank you!